# Refactor two linq queries into one single query

Tags: linq

I have a method with two linq statements which only have one difference. One query groups by 3 parameters and the other only groups by 2.  I'm sure there is a better way to refactor these two linq queries into one, but not sure how?

```
 public List<ReportEntry> GetReportData(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int companyId, bool groupByVATandPatAcc)
    {
        var results =
            from cy in _dc.Companies
            join cyv in _dc.CompanyVersions on cy.CompanyId equals cyv.CompanyId
            join cyd in _dc.CompanyDetails on cyv.CompanyVersionId equals cyd.Id
            join cd in _dc.CustomerDetails on cy.CompanyId equals cd.CompanyId
            join d in _dc.Documents on cd.CustomerId equals d.CustomerId
            join di in _dc.DocumentItems on d.DocumentId equals di.DocumentId
            join dd in _dc.DocumentDetails on di.DocDetailsId equals dd.DocumentDetailsId
            join vt in _dc.Vats on dd.VATCode equals vt.VATCode
            join a in _dc.Automobiles on d.AutomobileId equals a.AutomobileId into other2
            from o2 in other2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join v in _dc.Vouchers on dd.DocumentDetailsId equals v.DocDetailID into other1
            from o1 in other1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where (d.DocDate >= startDate && d.DocDate <= endDate) &&
                  (d.DocNumber > 0)
                  && (d.CompanyVersionId == cyv.CompanyVersionId)
                  && (d.isDeleted == false || d.isDeleted == null)
                  && (cy.CompanyId == companyId)
            select new
                   {
                       d.DocumentId,
                       d.DocTypeId,
                       cyd.Name,
                       dd.FisCostCenter,
                       dd.FisAccountCode,
                       dd.PatAccCode,
                       dd.VATCode,
                       cd.CustomerId,
                       cd.CustomerName,
                       d.DocNumber,
                       o2.Code,
                       d.DocDate,
                       d.GrossAmount,
                       o1.FromVoucNbr,
                       dd.VATAmount,
                       dd.NetAmount,
                       vt.VATDescr,
                       d.LastModUser,
                       d.StampValue
                   };


        // GA can have a single doc with multiple doc details 
        // Month End reports needs to SUM the multiple details into single doc
        if (groupByVATandPatAcc)
        {
            var singleDocuments = from d in results
                group d by new {d.DocumentId, d.VATCode, d.PatAccCode}
                into g
                select new
                       {
                           docId = g.Key,
                           g.First().DocTypeId,
                           g.First().DocDate,
                           g.First().Name,
                           g.First().CustomerId,
                           g.First().CustomerName,
                           g.First().DocNumber,
                           VATCode = g.First().VATCode.Trim(),
                           VATAmount = g.Sum(x => x.VATAmount),
                           NetAmount = g.Sum(x => x.NetAmount),
                           g.First().GrossAmount,
                           g.First().FisCostCenter,
                           g.First().FisAccountCode,
                           g.First().PatAccCode,
                           Code = g.First().Code.ToString(),
                           g.First().FromVoucNbr,
                           g.First().VATDescr,
                           g.First().LastModUser,
                           g.First().StampValue
                       };

            return singleDocuments.Select(
                d =>
                    new ReportEntry((Enums.DocTypes) d.DocTypeId, d.DocDate, d.Name, d.CustomerId, d.CustomerName,
                        d.DocNumber, d.VATCode.Trim(), d.VATAmount, d.NetAmount, d.GrossAmount
                        , d.FisCostCenter, d.FisAccountCode, d.PatAccCode, d.Code.ToString(), d.FromVoucNbr,
                        d.VATDescr, d.LastModUser, d.StampValue)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            var singleDocuments = from d in results
                                  group d by new { d.DocumentId, d.VATCode }
                                      into g
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          docId = g.Key,
                                          g.First().DocTypeId,
                                          g.First().DocDate,
                                          g.First().Name,
                                          g.First().CustomerId,
                                          g.First().CustomerName,
                                          g.First().DocNumber,
                                          VATCode = g.First().VATCode.Trim(),
                                          VATAmount = g.Sum(x => x.VATAmount),
                                          NetAmount = g.Sum(x => x.NetAmount),
                                          g.First().GrossAmount,
                                          g.First().FisCostCenter,
                                          g.First().FisAccountCode,
                                          g.First().PatAccCode,
                                          Code = g.First().Code.ToString(),
                                          g.First().FromVoucNbr,
                                          g.First().VATDescr,
                                          g.First().LastModUser,
                                          g.First().StampValue
                                      };

            return singleDocuments.Select(
                d =>
                    new ReportEntry((Enums.DocTypes)d.DocTypeId, d.DocDate, d.Name, d.CustomerId, d.CustomerName,
                        d.DocNumber, d.VATCode.Trim(), d.VATAmount, d.NetAmount, d.GrossAmount
                        , d.FisCostCenter, d.FisAccountCode, d.PatAccCode, d.Code.ToString(), d.FromVoucNbr,
                        d.VATDescr, d.LastModUser, d.StampValue)).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work?

```
// The original query with filters
var results = ...

// Group by 3 or 2 fields
results = groupByVATandPatAcc
    ? results.GroupBy(d => new { d.DocumentId, d.VATCode, d.PatAccCode });
    : results.GroupBy(d => new { d.DocumentId, d.VATCode });

// Return list
return results.Select(g => new ReportEntry(
      g.First().DocTypeId,
      g.First().DocDate,
      g.First().Name,
      g.First().CustomerId,
      g.First().CustomerName,
      g.First().DocNumber,
      VATCode = g.First().VATCode.Trim(),
      VATAmount = g.Sum(x => x.VATAmount),
      NetAmount = g.Sum(x => x.NetAmount),
      g.First().GrossAmount,
      g.First().FisCostCenter,
      g.First().FisAccountCode,
      g.First().PatAccCode,
      Code = g.First().Code.ToString(),
      g.First().FromVoucNbr,
      g.First().VATDescr,
      g.First().LastModUser,
      g.First().StampValue))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I need to  SUM the groupings also:
  VATAmount = g.Sum(x => x.VATAmount),
  NetAmount = g.Sum(x => x.NetAmount),

Comment: Edited my answer, you just need to select what you need from the grouped results.

Comment: I'm getting an error  on the  Group by 3 or 2 fields section. The error message is :   

Error 2 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,AnonymousType#2>>' and 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#3,AnonymousType#2>>

Comment: Ok, so you can't assign back to the results variable if you are using anonymous type in the original query. Try assigning to other variable instead or do the grouping and reportentry selection via navigation properties.